# Remove duplicates in array by checking if its the same as the next one

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, duplicates

I am learning JavaScript right now and I want to practice for loops and if statements. So I found a little exercise: **Remove all duplicates in the array**. I know there a probably better solutions but I want to know why my code isn't working. Can someone help me? Thx :)

```js
var arr = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5];
var b = 0;

function arrRemover() {
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        b++
        if (arr[b] == arr[b + 1]) {
            arr.splice[b + 1];
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

console.log(arrRemover());
```

Comment: `splice` is a method not an array where you can use `array indexing`. You have to call `splice` method with specific arguments

Comment: Why `b++` _before_ you start checking values?

Comment: now I noticed b++ is not necessary; i thought the i in the for loop is a local var and isn't readable outside of it

Comment: Since you haven't used `var` or `let` to define `i`, it's actually an implicit global variable but even if you did use `let`, your code is _inside_ that block, not _outside_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`splice` is a method so you have to call that method with specific arguments.

You don't need `b` here

> Better not to loop over that array from start instead loop from backward so that you won't skip over elements when you remove any element from an array beause if an elment gets deleted and you then counter increment and skip some elements

```js
var arr = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5];

function arrRemover() {
    for (let i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        if (arr[i] === arr[i - 1]) {
            arr.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

console.log(arrRemover());
```

You can also use `Set` here as:

```js
var arr = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5];

function arrRemover() {
    return [...new Set(arr)];
}

console.log(arrRemover());
```